# Reduce Javascript function length

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I have a javascript function that looks like that:

```
function myfun(){
//product.1
var t1=document.getElementById('1').innerHTML;
var link = document.getElementsByClassName(t1);

if(document.getElementsByClassName(t1).length==1){
document.getElementById(t1).innerHTML=link[0].outerHTML;
document.getElementById(t1).getElementsByTagName('a')[0].className='dsad';

}
if(document.getElementsByClassName(t1).length==2){
document.getElementById(t1).innerHTML=link[0].outerHTML+'; '+link[1].outerHTML;
var element = document.getElementById(t1).getElementsByTagName('a')[0].className='dsad';
var element2 = document.getElementById(t1).getElementsByTagName('a')[1].className='dsad';
}...
//product.2
var t2=document.getElementById('2').innerHTML;
```

It goes like that till `if(document.getElementsByClassName(t1).length==10)` and then it continues element - `document.getElementById('2')` and so on until it reach Element number `10`. The whole script is about 700 lines and I want to reduce it somehow. I was thinking of a for loop but I don't see how I could implement this. Any suggestions?

Comment: What about passing the element's `id` attribute to a function and then calling that function over and over within a loop?

Comment: have you ever heard about the for loop?

Comment: I don't usually link to W3Schools, but the example they use for a `for loop` is exactly what you're looking for. http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp

Comment: In addition to what you already show us, it would be good to have an idea of the HTML structure you have. Maybe there's even a simple way to select things. By the way, once you have done `var link = document.getElementsByClassName(t1);` , you can then refer to that element using the variable name `link` , so in the next line you can write : `if(link.length==1){`

Comment: I am puzzled you use `t1` both for lookup by class and id.

Comment: @mvw > Yes, I don't think this code would be working neither, but I may miss something, that's why I asked for some HTML

Comment: The code is working fine. I know it can be improved but I wanted to make it work first.

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
for( i = 1; i <= 10; i++ ){  
  if( document.getElementsByClassName( t1 ).length == i ){
    document.getElementById( t1 ).innerHTML=link[i-1].outerHTML;
    document.getElementById( t1 ).getElementsByTagName( 'a' )[ i-1 ].className = 'dsad';
  }
}
```

**EDIT:**

If you want also the element id to be increased you should try:

```
for( i = 1; i <= 10; i++ ){  

var t1=document.getElementById(''+i).innerHTML;
var link = document.getElementsByClassName(t1);

      if( document.getElementsByClassName( t1 ).length == i ){
        document.getElementById( t1 ).innerHTML=link[i-1].outerHTML;
        document.getElementById( t1 ).getElementsByTagName( 'a' )[ i-1 ].className = 'dsad';
      }
    }
```

Comment: the ElementID, t1 in this case, should also increase

Comment: @user986959 So increment it

Comment: u need 2 loops one nested inside another. One for ids, two for lengths

Comment: @user986959 do you have multiple elements carrying the same id ? try to avoid that. and you might be interested in using [jquery](http://jquery.com), a cross-browser js library abstracting away from many browser and dom idiosyncrasies while providing useful additional apis.

Comment: If you put the repeating `document.getElementById(t1)` into a variable, like `var el = document.getElementById(t1);` and use it subsequently, you get it even smaller.

Comment: You hadn't answered all the question, you have now and I've reverted. Smelt of *must answer first* syndrome!

Comment: @Liam ok but he OP added all the information after i had answered

Comment: Alls well that ends well! [The fastest gun isn't always the best](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem)

Answer (score 3):

You could try this:

```
for(var id=1;id<=10;id++){
    var t1id=""+id;
    var t1=document.getElementById(t1id).innerHTML;
    var link = document.getElementsByClassName(t1);
    for(var num=1;num<=10;num++){
        if(document.getElementsByClassName(t1).length==num){
             document.getElementById(t1).innerHTML=link[0].outerHTML;
             document.getElementById(t1).getElementsByTagName('a')[0].className='dsad';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't need the `var t1id=""+id;` line, but this is the actual (not answering as quickly as possible) answer

Answer (score 3):

```
function myfun(){
    for(i=1;i<=10;i++){
        var ti=document.getElementById(i).innerHTML;
        var link = document.getElementsByClassName("t" + i);

        if(link.length==1){
             link.innerHTML=link[0].outerHTML;
             ti.getElementsByTagName('a')[i - 1].className='dsad';

        }
        else if(link.length==2){
            ti.innerHTML=link[i - 1].outerHTML+'; '+link[i].outerHTML;
            var element = ti.getElementsByTagName('a')[i - 1].className='dsad';
            var element2 = ti.getElementsByTagName('a')[i].className='dsad';
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: Could do with some vague explanation?

Comment: well I thnk that what he is trying to do is finding out if there are only one or more than one elements with a single class name, I think that this function is clear enough to point him/her in the right direction

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure about one part of your code. So I am going to assume that is different depending on the id.

The first I would do is to create a javascript object with the content that you want to include for your className

```
var classNameDictionary = { 0 : 'dsad', 1 :'dsad, ...};
```

Once you have this, then I will implement a for loop as following:

```
function myFun(numElements){
    for(var i = 0; i < numElements; i++) {
        var t = document.getElementById(''+i).innerHTML;
        var link = document.getElementsByClassName(t);
        document.getElementById(t).innerHTML = "";
        for(var j = 0; j < link.length; j++) {
            document.getElementById(t).innerHTML +=link[j].outerHTML;
            var element = document.getElementById(t).getElementsByTagName('a')[j].className = classNameDictionary[j];
        }

    }
}
```

I hope it helps